# PHP Laravel 5 User class properties not accessible for sending Email after account creation

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5, account

I have a problem where I can't put in the variables into the Mail::send() function in laravel. Please see the following code:

```
$first_name = $request->input('first_name'),
$email = $request->input('email'),

//Create account

User::create([
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
]);

//Send email to user

Mail::send('emails.test', ['fname' => $first_name], function($message)
{
    $message->to($email)
            ->subject('Welcome!');
});

return redirect()
    ->route('home')
    ->with('info', 'Your account has been created and an authentication link has been sent to the email address that you provided. Please go to your email inbox and click on the link in order to complete the registration.');
```

For some reason the code breaks when it gets to the send email because I receive the error and the data is sent to the database. Why is the variable no longer accessible afterwards?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

In other words, `$email` has to be inherited like this:

```
Mail::send('emails.test', ['fname' => $first_name], function($message) use ($email)
{
    $message->to($email)
            ->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Note: `use ($email)` in the first line.

Comment: This is why I should learn the basics of php before jumping into framework projects. Thank you

Comment: is it possible to pass in multiple global variables such as use($email, $name, $fname, $lname) etc. This didn't seem to work but maybe its a different problem in my code :/